# Setting a SQL Azure server's name

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

One can create a SQL Server on Azure with cmdlet New-AzureSqlDatabaseServer

But how is it possible to set the server name? Azure gave an automatic name, but it is not easy to get it back later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the Azure Sql Server name with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163526.aspx

But you will need to change the azure mode to Azure Resource Manager mode with this:
Switch-AzureMode –Name AzureResourceManager

You will also need the latest Azure powershell module here:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/